# OneLiner for getting first element fo List (without using external functions or a `do` block)

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if there's an elegant way of parsing the first element of a list without using any other external function or a do block.

Similarly:

```
f lst = ... -- get the first element of lst using a single line
```

edit: if `lst` is not a parameter of `f`, is it possible to get the firest element of the list in oneLine (without using any external functions ofc)
is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible:

```
f (a:other) = a
```

This will work for any non-empty list.

Comment: I need `f` to do more than just be `a`. I will edit the question and mention that if `lst` is not a parameter of `f`, is it possible to get a value of the first element in oneline?

Comment: @user1094822, where does `lst` come from, then? Is it a global variable?

Comment: `f = case lst of { [] -> ...; (a:_) -> ...}`?

Comment: @ForceBru it is.

Comment: @chepner nice! how can the value of the `case` clause be passed thru `>>=`?

Comment: The same as any other value; `case` is an expression. `case [3,4] of { [] -> 0; (a:_) -> a; } == 3`.